# How to define a custom description environment?

Tags: environments, lists, enumitem, description

I want to define a new "custom-`description`" environment, say `my description` that taken in one length argument and produces the result that is achieved by the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
    
    Here's some text before the list.
    
    \begin{description}[align=right, itemindent=0cm, leftmargin=\labelsep+3cm, font=\ttfamily]
        \item [The first item] Math is so good!
        \item [Here's the second one!] Let's do some math!
    \end{description}

    And here's something for after the list.
    
\end{document}
```

Here, in `leftmargin=3cm+\labelsep`, `3cm` is where I want to pass my "length" parameter.

The output of the above code looks like this:

[image]

**Another thing:** It'd be super convenient if I can also pass another parameter to control the  value `font` among `\ttfamily`, `bfseries`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just

```tex
% definition
\NewDocumentEnvironment{my desp}{ m m }{%
  \begin{description}[align=right, itemindent=0cm, leftmargin=\labelsep+#1, font=#2]
}{
  \end{description}%
}

% usage
\begin{my desp}{3cm}{\ttfamily}
  \item ...
  \item ...
\end{my desp}
```

?

Full example

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{my desp}{ m m }{%
  \begin{description}[align=right, itemindent=0cm, leftmargin=\labelsep+#1, font=#2]
}{
  \end{description}%
}

\begin{document}
    
    Here's some text before the list.
    
    \begin{description}[align=right, itemindent=0cm, leftmargin=\labelsep+3cm, font=\ttfamily]
        \item [The first item] Math is so good!
        \item [Here's the second one!] Let's do some math!
    \end{description}

    And here's something for after the list.
    
    \begin{my desp}{3cm}{\ttfamily}
        \item [The first item] Math is so good!
        \item [Here's the second one!] Let's do some math!
    \end{my desp}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Thanks. Can you explain what `m m` means?

Comment: One `m` stands for one mandatory argument. See the `xparse` package manual for full doc for `\NewDocumentEnvironment`. Hmm actually `\newenvironment` is enough here.